# The value of an instance variable on NEAR - shared among every client? Or unique per client?

Tags: rust, blockchain, smartcontracts, nearprotocol

Suppose I have this simple code in a smart contract:

```
#[near_bindgen]
pub struct A {
    pub var1: AccountId,
    pub var2: Balance,
    pub my_map: TreeMap<String, (u128, u128, u128)>,
}

#[near_bindgen]
impl A {
    #[init]
    pub fn init() -> Self {
        let _my_map: TreeMap<String, (u128, u128, u128)> = TreeMap::new(b"t");
        Self {
          //...other fields
          my_map: _my_map
        }
    }

    //!!!
    // will this work properly for each client at all?
    //
    pub fn my_method1(&mut self) {

        // !! instance variable !!
        if !self.my_map.contains_key("some_key") {
            self.my_map.insert(&"aaa", &(1, 2, 3));
        } else {
           // already exists, error!
        }
    }
}
```

In the **ordinary environment** this Rust code would everyone to have his *own* instance of `A` and with its unique values of the fields. Correct?

Do I understand correctly, that in NEAR everyone -- client -- would have the **same instance** of `A`?

Namely, the **instance** variable `A.my_map` would contain the **same data** for *every* client of a smart contract where this code may be used?

How about `A.var1` and `A.var2` then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A smart contract persists state between invocations. In your example, `my_map` and other variables will be the same every time anyone calls `my_method1` in your contract.

This state is persistent within the network your smart contract is deployed, meaning - for `testnet` and `mainnet` it’ll be separate.

If you wish, for example, to manage separate state for different callers, check out this example: https://github.com/near-examples/rust-status-message/blob/master/src/lib.rs
It uses a mapping between caller’s account ID and data related to it.